# How to enable the ability to use the two-finger UIAccessibility "escape" gesture on a modal view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm looking to add the capability for a popup view to be dismissed by using the "two-finger-z- gesture, via [accessibilityPerformEscape](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityAction_Protocol/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/accessibilityPerformEscape). I've added this code to the view, but I am not able to dismiss it with the z gesture, is there anything else i'm missing?

```
- (BOOL)accessibilityViewIsModal
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)accessibilityPerformEscape
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Have you practiced the escape gesture in other apps?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your implementation of `-accessibilityPerformEscape` is empty. It is your responsibility to dismiss the modal view in response to the action.